# Dynamic Icon Component breaks Jest test (in NextJS/React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, next.js

So very new to the community, because I usually find the answer to my questions just by searching the community. But this one I can't figure out.

**My Setup**

I am using NextJS just as a framework application, so I don't use any of its API abilities. So far no tests implemented, but now I got more time on my hands. I want to implement tests using Jest and later on implementing some e2e such as playwright. But for now Jest.

**The Problem**

So I am implementing Jest in my application, but somehow cannot run the test because I am using a Dynamic Icon Component within my application.

So what is this icon component I am talking about. I got tired of importing icons one by one in each page. So decided to create one component that has the name attribute, so I can pass it any SVG name and it would just render it on my screen.

```
// Icon.jsx

import Company from './icons/company.svg';

const iconTypes = {
  'company': Company,
}

const Icon = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  let Icon = iconTypes[name];
  return <Icon {...props} />;
};

export default Icon;
```

```
// next.config.json

module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
    });
    return config;
  },
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

So this pretty much allows me to import an Icon by simply saying on anypage:

```
<Icon name="company" />
```

Now when implementing Jest, this component causes a lot of troubles with running my tests. I get the following error, when running my test:

```
    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    
    Check your code at Icon.jsx:119.

...

      117 |   console.log(1111111, name)
      118 |   let Icon = iconTypes[name];
    > 119 |   return <Icon {...props} />;
          |          ^
      120 | };
      121 |
      122 | export default Icon;

      at printWarning (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:220:30)
      at error (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:196:5)
      at createElementWithValidation (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2215:7)
      at Icon (res/images/Icon.jsx:119:10)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17811:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19049:16)
```

So this error message I usually get when I pass in a name of an icon that does not exist.

So at this point I'm a bit confused on how to handle this? Is there a way to ignore this component when running the test? Or run it somehow.

**Some things I already tried**

```
//jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js"
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.js"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/libs(.*)$": "<rootDir>/libs$1",
    "^@/res(.*)$": "<rootDir>/res$1",
    "^@/store(.*)$": "<rootDir>/store$1",
    "^@/pages(.*)$": "<rootDir>/pages$1",
    '^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$': '<rootDir>/styleMock.js'
  },
};
```

```
// svgTransform.js

module.exports = {
  process() {
    return 'module.exports = {};';
  },
  getCacheKey() {
    // The output is always the same.
    return 'svgTransform';
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

Let me share my solution, so others can reference it.

So the issue was still related to svg importing in Jest. Seems like my svgTransform.js was just not doing what it was supposed to do. So I replaced it with a package called jest-transformer-svg and managed to solve it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transformer-svg